# Facebook App Profile page: Custom tab

Tags: facebook, profile

We've published a game on Facebook, everything is set and fine but I can't seem to add custom tabs to my "[App Profile Page](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=127337483972992&sk=app_283743208319386)". (The F8 and Livestream tabs are custom tabs)

The [docs page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/) says:

> Each new app has its own App Profile Page (for example, see Facebook Live's page). This Page is similar to other Pages and user profiles on Facebook, and it includes Wall and Info tabs as well as **other configurable tabs**.

Is there anyone familiar with adding custom tabs to a Facebook App Profile Page?

Answer (score 0):

I have recently noticed a bug preventing a tab application from being added to its own application page... maybe this is what you are seeing...

Comment: Lix, is there an option that normally allows that? Where can I find this option? Thanks!

Comment: it seems that the page just does not appear in the list o available locations... i fear we are at the mercy of facebook for now...

Comment: this WAS possible in the past - and all of my apps that I managed to do this with are still appearing on the page - it seems it is only for new additions...